# An array with empty values, adding to an array and deleting elements within an array

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, visual-studio, methods

I am doing a mini project in C# on a football team management thing. There needs to be an array which has a max size of 10, but to begin with it will hold only 5 teams.

Below is the code I am have used:

```
class FootballTeams
 {
    private string[] teams = new string[10] { "Everton", "Liverpool", "Arsenal", "Manchester United", "West Hame United", "", "", "", "", "" };


    public FootballTeams(){ }

    public void DisplayMenu()
    {   
      Console.WriteLine("Football Manager");
      Console.WriteLine();
      Console.WriteLine("1. Add a Football team");
      Console.WriteLine("2. List the Football teams");
      Console.WriteLine("3. Search for a Football team");
      Console.WriteLine("4. Delete a team");
      Console.ReadLine();
    }



    public void DisplayTeams()
    {
        foreach(var item in teams)
        Console.Write(item.ToString() + " ");
    }


  }
}
```

I do not know if I have created the string right. When the DisplayTeams method is called the 5 teams there are displayed. However I don't know if it is correct as I am going to add some more methods. One that will let the user enter a teams name and it will be added to the array and one that lets the user define a team that they would like to delete, with the contents of the array being updated and displayed after.

I am noob with C# so any help would be great!

Comment: Remove Item from an array?. I think you should use a List<string>

Comment: I sort of looked into that, however there needs to be a cap of 10 teams. From the gist I got you can't do that?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Of course you can `List<string> data = new List<string>(10);`

Comment: Have I defined the array correctly, how do you add to an array after defining it and how to delete specific entries in the array.

Comment: Like I said Tijesunimi....I am new to C# :P, cheers, I will have a quick read up into using List<string>

Comment: you can decalre an ArrayList and keep adding the teams to the list as and when you want to.

Comment: With using what @Tijesunimi put, how do I populate it with some entities? e.g Everton, Arsenal and West Ham

Comment: @user2852418 `data.Add("Everton");`, etc.

Comment: @Tijesunimi I tried that before, but it come up with used like a type instead of a field

Comment: @Tijesunimi sorry I meant that the 'data' bit is flaggin an error saying it is a field but is being used like a type

Comment: Why would you do this as a console app?

Comment: @user2852418 Really, show the code you used to declare it

Comment: @Blam Teacher told us to

Comment: @Tijesunimi Exactly what I put in the initial post, with the original array replaced with the one you suggested

Comment: Is there any reading material you could suggest for using 'List'

Comment: This has turned into a discussion.  Take it to chat.

Comment: @Dan-o Don't think I have enough rep to....

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx and http://www.dotnetperls.com/list

Comment: @Tijesunim Ok, so instead if the initial array I had I have put  `public static void Main()
        {
            List<string> teams = new List<string>(10);
            teams.Add("Everton");
        }` above the constructor, how do I reference the List into the DisplayTeams method

Comment: @user2852418 That should work

Comment: @Tijesunim in `public void DisplayTeams()
    {
        foreach(var item in teams)
        Console.Write(item.ToString() + " ");
    }` the `teams` does not exist in the current context error occurs

Comment: @user2852418 Just upvoted two of your posts. Lets take this to chat...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42439/discussion-between-user2852418-and-tijesunimi)

Answer (score 0):

Arrays have predefined length and indexes and cannot be changed
if you want to make a DYNAMIC LIST of TEAMS you better use LIST instead of Array
List type allows you to manage your data easily
i.e. they have predefined functions you can add or remove any Teams easily and the list will take care of the index

you can also use a list like you use arrays with their indexes

example

List Team = new List();

```
Team.add("XYZ");
Team.add("XYZ");
Team.add("XYZ");
Team.add("XYZ");
```